How to fill a virtual background WebRTC in Flutter web app
I have developed a web app that provides video calls, built using Flutter for web.
Now I want to add a feature such as a virtual background or blur effect to protect the privacy of participants.
However, I can't find the way to do this.
I would be happy if someone could explain that both methodologically and roughly.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
